# In future say around 2500 , will everything would be free of cost in this world?

Tags: economy, post-scarcity

In the future will money / trade system will diminish and everything will be free .

i.e all humans contribute to society in one way or another and in turn take what ever they want from society and everything is free.

Also all humans will become responsible and also no human will be greedy and won't store anything for themselves .And learn it give up anything .

Will such a system come to existence and will it survive ,what are the steps to make this system happen  ?

What are the steps taken by government to help this system come into existence ?

Comment: Utopia, communism, anarchy are all possible answers to this question. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Why on Earth (or off it :-)) would you think this would happen?  There was a guy by the name of Karl Marx came up with this idea a while back.  Some people tried to implement it, but discovered it didn't work all that well.  See history of the 20th century.

Comment: This doesn't really sound like worldbuilding to me, more like a guess at the real future of humanity. We can't know this. How can we help you build a world?

Comment: You are describing the world of Star Trek. Whether it's a reasonable future depends on how optimistic you are, I guess.

Comment: I would say it's possible when **human selfishness** get removed. But I'm not sure it's a good thing or not.

Comment: @jamesqf Somebody tried to implement Marx's ideas in the 20th century? What a surprise! There were two experiments in State Capitalism in the totalitarian Soviet Union and China which disguised this with Marxist doctrine. They failed, thus demonstrating State Capitalism doesn't work. Marx wasn't a Marxist & his ideas were different from those as practiced. Old Karl would have been horrified about what done in his name.

Comment: @Erik I'm not sure Star Trek counts as post-scarcity as intended by the OP. Sure, they rarely need to concern themselves with resource scarcity in everyday life and for basic needs, but scarcity of various resources, not the least of which being energy, **is** a consideration in a non-negligible number of situations that we get to see on screen.

Comment: I removed the [near-future] tag, which is generally taken to mean quite soon (and certainly within a lifetime), and replaced it with the [post-scarcity] tag, which I think better categorizes this question.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling for Starfleet itself, yes. The idea is that for those living on Earth, it's a post-scarcity situation.

Comment: @Erik Good point.

Comment: What might actually happen is that every person will have a really good paying job which will also make products more expensive, but everyone will live happy and comfortable.

Comment: The capitalist system depends on a shortage of products & services. When *Star Trek* like replicators are invented and robots that can do most of the jobs, there won't be much work left or nothing left to trade and capitalism will lose its relevance. That's not to say there will be nothing left to do - most of it will be creative work, but no one will have any money to pay the creative people. With all the boring / menial jobs being done by robots, people will turn to interesting ones like hobbies. This could result in a cultural shift that would make us value our contributions to society.

Comment: Obviously, the world will be much more worse if there is no money. I don't think companies, job applicants, and students will work to the best of their effort when money is gone. Think of it, money is basically the reason why many of us strives to success. Without it, people would be terribly spoiled. And I'm telling you, much more crimes will occur.

Comment: @BookStriker It is easy to draw conclusions based on how society now works, but if the entire system have changed, then there is no guarantee that the current values and motivational forces will have any impact. Studying should be done motivated by an urge to learn, not by a chance to get a higher salary; if this changes then only those with a desire to learn and improve will study in a money-less future. This could perhaps lead to that only those best motivated to improve will study and, thus, society at large will be better off than if mainly people only motivated by greed does.

Comment: @BookStriker Also, if one lives in a post scarcity society, then arguably *fewer* crimes will occur. Many crimes of today are caused by the large gap between the rich and the poor; those poor find no other way than to steal to survive (and often feel so neglected by society to not care that stealing is wrong), those rich are driven by greed and steal to become even richer and more powerful. In a world where everyone have a surplus of what they need, there will be less inclination to commit crimes related to materialistic reasons. Crimes related to passion will likely be unaffected.

Comment: @Alexander von Wernherr please remove hold , many good answers are staying in comments..

Comment: @Erik: You need to remember that Star Trek (at least from my second-hand knowledge - I'm not a fan) is a military organization.  It's really no different from say today's navy, in which food, clothing, housing &c (and a lot more if you're an officer) are provided as part of the job.  They're not 'free' in any sense: the taxpayers back home are picking up the tab.

Comment: @Mrkvička: There will always be scarcity, though the things which are scarce may change.  For instance, a couple of centuries ago uncrowded space was cheap, if not free, but a lot of material goods were expensive (if they could be had at all).  Nowadays electronic gadgets and such are cheap, but uncrowded space is available only to the most prosperous.

Comment: @jamesqf: the people on Earth in Star Trek don't pay taxes because they have plenty of everything. They don't even have money anymore in Star Trek.

Comment: @Erik: Well, that's what you get when you start deriving your ideas of the real world from TV shows :-)  It's the same as running your warp engines off a perpetual motion machine... excuse me, "dilithium crystals".

Comment: @jamesqf: to be fair; if you have spaceships and replicators, there really IS enough of everything to go around. They can disassemble the entire solar system, just to support one little planet. As long as you are content with living on Earth, you can have all the goods you want.

Comment: @jamesqf I agree that reaching a post scarcity society will be hard, if nigh impossible, but that's mainly because people *want* things to be scarce, not because they need to be. The first step towards a post scarcity society would be to change peoples attitude towards greed, which also happen to be one of the hardest steps. Once people stop desiring more than they need, then we can achieve it. I personally believe it's more than a millennia there. As for space: we can currently be as few as 50 ppl/km² if we spread out, but since everyone want to live in the best areas, it gets much denser.

Comment: @Erik: But replicators are where you cross the line between SF and fantasy.  Even if you could build a working replicator, it would only replicate things. Maybe I have to keep hitting on the point that there's only " one little planet", so unless you can figure out how to do major population reductions, there's not enough room for everyone.  So everyone would have endless replicated tech gadgets, but only the mega-rich would be able to hike, ski, ride horses, &c - most of what I do to make life enjoyable, rather than economic drudgery.

Comment: @Mrkvička: To me, 50 people/km²  is intolerably crowded.  1 person per 50 km² would be better :-)

Comment: @jamesqf Then it is highly beneficial that people desire different things; with so many people wanting to live crowded, it makes the space outside cities so much more roomy ;)

Comment: @Mrkvička: Well, there's the rub.  Do all of the people who live in crowded cities actually want to live there, or are they there because that's where they can make money?  (Certainly that's why I spent parts of my life in such places: to get enough money so that I could afford to live elsewhere.)  But in a non-scarcity economy, no one should have to live in a city for economic reasons, no?  So lots of them would want to leave for uncrowded rural areas, but there wouldn't be enough rural to go around, thus creating a new scarcity.

Comment: @jamesqf That will be a question for the future. I believe that there will always be people who want to live in cities due to the closeness to whatever they might be interested in (food, art, culture, who knows), but there will likely be less wanting to live in cities than there is now. If people have already abandoned greed, then there won't be an artificial space scarcity created as no one will want to earn money from it; in that case people will spread out as reasonable as they can and hopefully everyone will be happy with the space they get. If they haven't abandoned greed...

Comment: @Mrkvička: Wanting to have a decent life isn't greed.  Of course the only actual answer comes from experiment - that is, establish such a society and see what happens.  Unfortunately, we don't have the necessary time machines, so the best we can do is use logic and our knowledge of humans to try to project what might happen.  Personally, I think the whole idea of replicator-based "abundance" is nothing more than wishful thinking on the part of people who just can't get over the fact that Marx's ideas didn't work in practice.

Comment: @jamesqf I didn't mean to say that wanting a decent life is greed, but if someone wants much more than a decent life at the cost of others' decent life, then it is. I also find it unfair to claim that Marx's ideas didn't work in real life seeing that it's barely been tested, looking at USSR or China is misleading as neither have tried it for real. Cuba, on the other hand, were closer to the real thing and there it worked decently (but far from perfectly) and the town [Marinaleda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marinaleda) in Spain is fairly close to real communism too, and their version works.

Comment: @jamesqf I don't think replicator technology will ever work as in the movies (one reason is the too high power consumption), but I hope that I am wrong. It is also not really required to go as far as replicators as we have enough resources for everyone to have a decent life, but the distribution is hindered partially because of logistics and partially because a lot of people feel entitled to have *way* more than what they will ever need. I believe that a real post scarcity society cannot function with the current way we behave, but whether we will change or not is impossible to predict.

Comment: @Mrkvička: No, we don't have enough resources for everyone to have a decent life, unless your replicators can build enough new, unpopulated planets for all of us to have enough open space to be comfortable.  That's my point: you never get rid of scarcity, it's just that different things become scarce.

Comment: @jamesqf I am getting intrigued - I touch this very subject in my writing, but I haven't actually met anyone who'd refuse to have people closer than 50km² - would you mind giving me some more of your thoughts? I created a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53601/space-as-scarce-commodity) so we don't spam this question more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Trade

Trade cannot disappear, because it is essential for civilized life. Man is born naked and helpless, and in order to thrive he needs nurturing, education, shelter, food, clothes, and so on. In order to satisfy his needs, man trades goods and services for other goods and services. Even some animals do it. There is no way to do away with trade without reducing man to the life of a mindless beast.

### Money

Money was invented in order to facilitate trade. Without money, trade takes by necessity the form of [barter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barter), where goods and services are exchanged directly for other goods and services. (See [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63124/what-point-in-a-society-does-a-royal-mint-become-important/63208#63208) for a more detailed account.) Money was used since ancient times as a universally accepted medium of exchange, in order to eliminate the complexities of barter.

In the future this may not necessarily be necessary anymore.

[Marvin Minsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_Minsky), one of the legendary figures in Artificial Intelligence research, hypothesized that with the development of IT, there may come a future when

> With fast computers and huge memories, we could have a nonlinear database that would better understand what each person has and wants. Then, by using complicated game theory-related computations, it might turn out that in general everyone would get more (in terms of their personal values) for the goods that they are willing to “sell”.

(See for example [here](http://kingsreview.co.uk/articles/money-is-a-technology-ii/) and [here](http://discovermagazine.com/1998/oct/thefiscalfrontie1520).)

He was quick to add that

> I don't think anyone will care that much--at least in the distant future, because once the intelligent robots come, we could all be as wealthy as kings.

Comment: Many species of animal, and carnivores in particular, are helpless at birth and require various kinds of nurturing. This does not mean that lions, whales or kangaroos have what we would recognize as an "economy" in order to tend to their young.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Chimpanzees pick bugs off each other. Would that be considered a trade?